Appending one div from a seperate component into another in React
I create a Note with an inputbox and I can't figure out how to append the note into the div of the inputbox. The Inputbox is in the CreateArea-function inside the CreateArea.jsx, the Note-function with the props and layout is in the Note.jsx and both files get exported to the App.jsx. The Inputbox and the calendar are inside the container-div, which has the grid-layout. First the return-code of the CreateArea.jsx:
return (
    // Container with the Grid-Layout
    <div className="container">
    
    // Code for the static MUI Calendar
    <ThemeProvider theme={themeCalendar}>
    <div className="calendar">
      
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      
      <StaticDateTimePicker
        slotProps={{actionBar : {actions : []}}}
        orientation="landscape"
        value={value}
        onChange={test} 
      />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
    
    // Code for the MUI Datetimefield
    <ThemeProvider theme={themeInputbox}>
      <div className="formarea">
      <form className="create-note">
          
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      
      <DateTimeField
        label=""
        value={value}
        onChange={test}
        slotProps={{ textField: { variant: 'standard'} }}
        
      />
      
       </LocalizationProvider>
        // Inside this Textarea I write the Todo
        <textarea
          name="content"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={note.content}
          placeholder="write a note..."
          rows="3"
        />
        // Add icon to add the Todo with the Date and time
        <Fab color="primary" onClick={submitNote}><AddIcon/></Fab>
        
      </form>
      </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateArea;

Now of the Note.jsx:
 return (
    // The Note-div with the props
    <div className="note">
      <h1>{props.date}</h1>
      <p>{props.time}</p>
      <p>{props.content}</p>
      //Delete a Note-Icon
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        <DoneIcon />
      </button>
    </div>
    
  );
}

And finally of App.jsx:
return (
      <div>
      <Header />
      // In the App-Component all Notes get mapped into a Todo-List
      <CreateArea onAdd={addNote}/>
      {notes.map((noteItem, index) => {
        return (
          <Note
            key={index}
            id={index}
            date={noteItem.date}
            time={noteItem.time}
            content={noteItem.content}
            onDelete={deleteNote}
          />
        );
      })
      }
      <Footer />
    </div>  
  );
  
}

export default App;

Here I show you the the grid I want to place the created Notes in floating left:
enter image description here
I want to place the Notes inside the bottom-left Grid-Area. I tried the grid-area command, but it doesn't work since the note-div is not inside the div of the inputarea and the calendar. Then I tried many things but nothing worked. I researched a solution but got more confused and it didn't seem to work out in my case.
I would really appreciate any solution and maybe with some explanation.
I tried many things but nothing worked out. It seems that I miss some basic understanding of React...

The easiest way would be to just write the following in your Note.js file:
<div className="note" extends CreateArea>

This is not working for me the layout didnt change at all.
